# Android characteristic.getValue empty array

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

Sometimes, if a GATT notification occurs, and I try to get the characteristic value through `characteristic.getValue()` multiple times, the call suddenly starts to return an empty array.

That mostly happens on the first notification in that connection, and seems to be quite random.

How can I get `characteristic.getValue()` to be consistent?

I have a Pixel 3; maybe it's an implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `characteristic.getValue()` once per notification, and store it in some variable. You should not call that every time you need to reference that data. If you are calling that multiple times after a single notification, it will not work.

Ideally you are using the service example provided by Google, and pushing the notification data to a variable in the desired activity. This will happen automatically after using `setCharacteristicNotification` on the desired characteristic, and the update is performed in the `broadcastUpdate` whenever a notification broadcast is received. (Assuming you connect the 'plumbing' in you application)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although that would be new for me. It seems like it is really a bug in my stack. Do you have any official sources confirming your statement?